# VoiceXML interpreter notification when prompt was played

Tags: notifications, prompt, voicexml

Is there any option (probably a tag) to tell the VoiceXML interpreter to notify my VXML application when he completes playing all the prompts from the most recent VoiceXML page?

Answer (score 0):

No standard mechanism that I know of.

You could insert an input (form) with a very short timeout to allow you to know when the prompts were done.  If you are supporting barge in, use the right grammar(s).  If not, you can just use a dummy grammar.